# Duplicate and rename vs make a blank sheet and name

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to duplicate and name multiple copies of a sheet that already has data. The rename would be based on a list from another sheet in the same workbook.

This script does that, but only generates new blank sheets. Can this be modified to duplicate and rename vs make a blank sheet and name?

Sheet to duplicate in this instance is "FO_VFX_010" but if that could be any name, even better.
The sheet with the names is labeled as is "All_shots" the column is A rows 2- whatever.

Here's the existing code from someone else's post.

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Create New Tabs', 'createTabs')
        .addToUi()}

function createTabs() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    ss.getSheetByName('Names').getRange('A:A').getValues().filter(String)
        .forEach(function (sn) {
            if (!ss.getSheetByName(sn[0])) {
                ss.insertSheet(sn[0], ss.getSheets().length);}})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to duplicate a sheet containing an existing template AND give the new sheet a predetermined name.

In this answer, the list of sheet names is taken from Column A of "All shots", and the method to duplicate the template is a specifically designed for templates:
`insertSheet(sheetName, options)` [Doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-options)

---

```
function buildsheets() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //define all shots
  var sourcename = "All_shots";
  var allshots = ss.getSheetByName(sourcename)
  
  // define shot_001 - initial template
  var templatename = "shot_001"
  var templatesheet = ss.getSheetByName(templatename)
  
  // get the number of sheet names
  // assume row 1 = shot_001 has already been created
  var Avals = allshots.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log("the number of rows of sheets = "+Alast);
  
  // get the data from all shots
  var sourcedata = allshots.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // loop through the sheet names on All_Shots
  for (var i = 1; i<Alast+1; i++){
    
    var name = sourcedata[i][0]; 
    ss.insertSheet(name, {template: templatesheet});
    var newsheet = ss.getSheetByName(name)
    var target = newsheet.getRange("A1");
    target.setValue(name);

  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

---

**Sheet = "All_shots"**

This shows the proposed sheet names in Column A, and other relevant data in Column B
[image: All Shots]

---

**The initial template - shot_001**

This shows the format of the initial sheet to be used as the template
[image: Shot_001]

---

**Duplicate template**

This shows the first duplicate of the template based on the names list on "All_shots". Note the value in cell C3 has been updated to reflect the matching data on "All_shots"
[image: Duplicate]

---

**New template sheets**

This shows the newly created sheets "shot_002", "shot_003" and "shot_004" (the names come from the list in Column A of "All_shots"). In this example, there are only three duplicates made but the same code applies for any range in Column A of "All_shots.

[image: New sheets]

Answer (score 0):

This is fantastic!

I kit-bashed what you provided, changed a couple names and viola! It's a masterpiece! totally works the way I need! you ROCK!

This is the final form:

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('buildsheets')
        .addItem('buildsheets', 'buildsheets')
        .addToUi()}

function buildsheets() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //define All_shots
  var sourcename = "All_shots";
  var All_shots = ss.getSheetByName(sourcename)
  
  // define Template - initial template
  var templatename = "Template"
  var templatesheet = ss.getSheetByName(templatename)
  
  // get the number of sheet names
  // assume row 1 = Template has already been created
  var Avals = All_shots.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log("the number of rows of sheets = "+Alast);
  
  // get the data from all shots
  var sourcedata = All_shots.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // loop through the sheet names on All_Shots
  for (var i = 1; i<Alast+1; i++){
    
    var name = sourcedata[i][0]; 
    ss.insertSheet(name, {template: templatesheet});
    var newsheet = ss.getSheetByName(name)
    var target = newsheet.getRange("A1");
    target.setValue(name);

  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```